# run 2 main via exec-maven-plugin with 2 profils

Tags: maven, profile

I want run 2 main via exec-maven-plugin with 2 profiles. In my production I user only "prod" profile and in my continus integration I want use "preProd" profile and "prod" profile.

in prod

> mvn -Pprod

in continus integration:

> mvn -PpreProd,prod

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>preProd</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>CountContinusIntegr-execution</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.CountContinusIntegr</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>RunMyProd-execution</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.RunMyProd</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I run maven command, I have this logs (com.mycompany.RunMyProd.main() run 2 times):

[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (CountContinusIntegr-execution) @ myproject ---
[2016-12-06 15:44:44]: Reading file scenarios.properties
0 [**com.mycompany.RunMyProd**.main()] INFO ....
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (RunMyProd-execution) @ myproject ---
[2016-12-06 15:44:45]: Reading file scenarios.properties
0 [**com.mycompany.RunMyProd**.main()] INFO ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I find the solution:** `I put <configuration> in <execution>`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>preProd</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>CountContinusIntegr-execution</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.CountContinusIntegr</mainClass>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>RunMyProd-execution</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.RunMyProd</mainClass>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```